# Node.js - child_process and cluster confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

Take this brief example: I have a file called `parent.js`, with the following code:

```
var child_process = require('child_process')
var forker = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/child.js')

forker.on('message', function (msg) {
console.log('PARENT got message:', msg)
})

// sends a message to the forked process?
forker.send({msg: 'Parent message.'})
```

**First question**: am I getting this right? `child_process.fork()` returns the *forker* process, doesn't it? (like `child_process.spawn()`?)

Anyway, here's the code for `child.js`:

```
process.on('message', function (msg) {
console.log('CHILD got message:', msg)
})

// sends a message to the forker process? why?
process.send({msg: 'Message from the child.'})
```

**Second question**: what does `process` refer to inside the child process? To the current forked process I guess? If so, when I call `process.send()` I'm sending a message to the parent process right?

**Third question**: take this example (simplified version from [Node: Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920015956.do)):

```
var cluster = require('cluster')

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // fork child...
    var worker = cluster.fork()
    worker.on('message', function (msg) {
        // do stuff
    })
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
    process.send(aMessage)
}
```

What I find unclear is: `worker` is kind of the `forker` of the previous example? And `process.send()` inside the worker sends a message to the *forker* process?

Comment: child_process, cluster still confuse me

Answer (score 15):

1) `child_process.fork()` returns the forked process in the same way as `child_process.spawn()` returns the newly spawned process. Indeed, `fork()` is just

> [...] a special case of the `spawn()` functionality for spawning Node processes. In addition to having all the methods in a normal ChildProcess instance, the returned object has a communication channel built-in.[1](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

2) `process` in the child refers to the child `process`. Also,

> In the child the process object will have a send() method, and process will emit objects each time it receives a message on its channel.[2](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle)

So from within the child we can send messaged with 'send()' and we can receive them with `.on('message')`. Like in your snippet.

3) As stated in the documentation about the `cluster` module on Node.js:

> The worker processes are spawned using the `child_process.fork method`, so that they can communicate with the parent via IPC and pass server handles back and forth. [3](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_fork)

So you're right. Node cluster wraps the functionality for `process` in a more usable way (please pay attention that at this point in time, the `cluster` module is marked as experimental. Api may change in the near future).

Comment: Ok, so when I set `process.on('message')` inside a worker I listen from messages sent by the master process, while when I do like `cluster.fork().on('message')` inside the master process what happens specifically? Who listens for messages from whom in the second case?

Comment: the child process, because `cluster.fork()` returns a child process.

Comment: Actually by playing with this code, it ends up that by doing  `cluster.fork().on('message')`, it's the master process which listens for messages sent by the just forked process (with `process.send()`). In order to listen for messages *from the master*, the master should do `cluster.fork().send()` while the worker should do `process.on('message')` (or `cluster.worker.on('message')`).